# Passing props to children in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms, formik

I'm trying to make a **Formik wrapper** which takes `children` as props and would **render anything put inside**. There are a couple forms to make which take different initial values and validation schema etc. The **only thing in common thing is the grid layout**. The goal is to have the access to **Formik [props](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#formik-render-methods-and-props)** like values, errors etc. in the child component and I have no idea how to pass it to its child. The form fields don't even show up.

The wrapper:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, FormikConfig, FormikValues } from "formik";
import { Col, Layout, Row } from "antd";

const FormContainer: React.FC<FormikConfig<FormikValues>> = ({ children, ...props }) => {
    return <Formik
        {...props}
    >
        {props => (
            <Layout>
                <Row style={{ height: "100vh", display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
                    <Col span={12}>
                        <Layout>
                            {/*this will be replaced with some background image*/}
                            <pre>{JSON.stringify(props.values, null, 2)}</pre>
                            <pre>{JSON.stringify(props.errors, null, 2)}</pre>
                        </Layout>
                    </Col>
                    <Col span={12}>
                        <Layout>
                            {/*here goes goes a Form from a different components*/}
                            {children}
                        </Layout>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Layout>
        )}
    </Formik>
};

export default FormContainer;
```

I must be doing something wrong. I am unable to get any Formik props/values from anywhere else when I wrap `FormContainer` around anything.

My form example (so far):

```
import React from "react";
import { Field, Form } from "formik";
import { Col, Form as AntForm, Icon, Input, Row } from "antd";
import { initialValues, validationSchema } from "./fieldValidation";
import FormContainer from "../../../containers/FormContainer/FormContainer";

const RegisterPage: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <FormContainer
            initialValues={initialValues}
            validationSchema={validationSchema}
            onSubmit={(data, { setSubmitting }) => {
                setSubmitting(true);

                setTimeout(() => {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
                    setSubmitting(false);
                }, 5000);
            }}
        >
            {({touched, errors}) => (
                <Form>
                    <Row gutter={[8, 8]}>
                        <Col span={12}>
                            <AntForm.Item
                                help={touched.firstName && errors.firstName ? errors.firstName : ""}
                                validateStatus={touched.firstName && errors.firstName ? "error" : undefined}
                            >
                                <Field
                                    name="firstName"
                                    prefix={<Icon type="solution" style={{ color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" }} />}
                                    placeholder="First name"
                                    as={Input}
                                />
                            </AntForm.Item>
                        </Col>
                        <Col span={12}>
                            <AntForm.Item
                                help={touched.lastName && errors.lastName ? errors.lastName : ""}
                                validateStatus={touched.lastName && errors.lastName ? "error" : undefined}
                            >
                                <Field
                                    name="lastName"
                                    prefix={<Icon type="solution" style={{ color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" }} />}
                                    placeholder="Last name"
                                    as={Input}
                                />
                            </AntForm.Item>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Form>
            )}
        </FormContainer>
    );
};

export default RegisterPage;
```

I'm stuck. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just at first glance, you're using `props` twice, once when destructuring the arguments passed to your wrapper, and then again to name the arguments for the child render function.  That seems a little weird to me; I think my IDE would be highlighting that as an error :)

Answer (score 13):

Here's how to pass the prop "propsToPass" from the parent to all his direct children:

```
const Parent = props => {
  const { children } = props;

  const childrenWithExtraProp = React.Children.map(children, child =>
    React.cloneElement(child, { propsToPass: "toChildren" })
  );

  return <div>{childrenWithExtraProp}</div>;
};

export default Parent;
```

So in this case, both children will have the prop "propsToPass"

```
<Parent>
  {/* this.props.propsToPass will be available in this component */}
  <Child></Child>
  {/* this.props.propsToPass will be available in this component */}
  <AnotherChild></AnotherChild>
</Parent>
```

You could do the same for your form.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see like rendering Formik as children is good idea here, especially that you are supposed to render one form in such FormWrapper. I would use render props here, so here is basic example how you can do it.

Anyway, I still can't get your concept of re-inventing FormWrapper if Formik provides its own wrapper:

https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik

```
interface FormWrapperProps extends FormikConfig<FormikValues> {
    renderForm(props: FormWrapperProps): React.ReactNode
}

export const RegisterForm = (props: FormWrapperProps) => (
    <form>
        <input type="text"/>
        <input type="text"/>
    </form>
)

const FormWrapper: React.FC<FormWrapperProps> = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="layout">
            {/*here goes goes a Form from a different components*/}
            {props.renderForm(props)}
        </div>
    )
}

const FormPage = () => {

    const props = {} as FormWrapperProps

    return (
        <FormWrapper
            {...props}
            renderForm={(props: FormWrapperProps) => <RegisterForm {...props} />}
        />
    )
}
```